# Why is amount and charge in my react code not rendering to the screen

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have an amount and charge that renders each time information is placed in the input form. I have been able to console the charge and amount and it prints to the console the right details but each time I click the submit button, it doesn't render on the page. I do not have any issue printed to the console. Can someone please help me check the code.

Here is the code structure for the `app.js`:

```
const initialExpenses = [
    { id: uuid(), charge: "rent", amount: 1600 },
    { id: uuid(), charge: "car payment", amount: 5000 },
    { id: uuid(), charge: "utility bills", amount: 800 }
];

function App() {
    // all expenses and add expenses
    const [expenses, setExpenses] = useState(initialExpenses);
    // Single charges
    const [charge, setCharge] = useState("");

    // Single amount
    const [amount, setAmount] = useState("");

    // Functionalities
    const handleCharge = (e) => {
        setCharge(e.target.value);
    };
    const handleAmount = (e) => {
        setAmount(e.target.value);

    }

    const handleSubmit = e => {
        console.log(amount, charge)
        e.preventDefault();
        if (charge !== '' && amount > 0) {
            // The above code using the short notation syntax in ES6 which means 
            charges: charges === charges, same for amount
                   const singleExpense = { id: uuid(), charge, amount }
            setExpenses([...expenses, singleExpense])
            setCharge("");
            // setAmount("")
        } else {
            // handleAlert
        }
    };

    return (
        <>
            <Alert />
            <h1>Budget Calculator</h1>
            <main className="App">
                <ExpenseForm
                    charge={charge}
                    amount={amount}
                    handleCharge={handleCharge}
                    handleAmount={handleAmount}
                    handleSubmit={handleSubmit}
                />
                <ExpenseList expenses={expenses} />
            </main>
            <h1>
                total spending: {" "}
                <span className="total">
                    #{expenses.reduce((acc, curr) => {
                    return (acc += parseInt(curr.amount))
                }, 0)}
                </span>
            </h1>
        </>
    );
}

export default App;


Here is the ExpenseForm code
const ExpenseForm = ({ amount, charge, expenses, handleCharge, handleAmount,
    handleSubmit }) => {
    return (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <div className="form-center">
                <div className="form-group">
                    <label htmlFor="charge">Charge</label>
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        className="form-control"
                        id="charge"
                        name="charge"
                        placeholder="Enter value here"
                        value={charge}
                        onChange={handleCharge}
                    />
                </div>

                <div className="form-group">
                    <label htmlFor="amount">Amount</label>
                    <input
                        type="value"
                        className="form-control"
                        id="amount"
                        name="amount"
                        placeholder="Enter value here"
                        value={amount}
                        onChange={handleAmount}
                    />
                </div>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" className="btn">
                Submit
                <MdSend className="btn-icon" />
            </button>
        </form>
    )
}

export default ExpenseForm;
```

Comment: does your ```console.log``` in ```handleSubmit``` fire?

Answer (score 0):

Several smaller mistakes, everything is working here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-lewin-uoz4g

1. I don't know what is your initial expenses state, must be []
2. If you want to set new state based on previous state, you have to yous callback:

```
setExpenses(previousStateExpenses => [
        ...previousStateExpenses,
        singleExpense
      ]);
```

I made some imports, and deleted `<Alert/>` which seemed not to be necessary for this to work.

Comment: Thank you for the knowledge shared, it actually worked fine. All correction has been noted too.

Comment: Hello Kindly help me take a look at this codesandbox link, getting wrong user from the github API   https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-gates-8sevk?file=/src/App.js

Comment: This is the correct api (you missed "search" in URL): `https://api.github.com/search/users?q=${text}`. Then the `setState` must be like this `users: res.data.items`

Comment: Thank you, just implemented your suggestion and it worked out fine. Thank you very. I don't know if you are willing to mentor a junior developer too. Waiting for your response and I would appreciate if you can drop your mail too